# Find Closest number in Data as Class in C# WPF have a error?

Tags: c#

I want to find Closest number from my local Table(Class) but I have a error !

This is my Class :

```
  public class ZnormalT
{
    public double ZB { get; set; }
    public double a0 { get; set; }
    public double a01 { get; set; }
    public double a02 { get; set; }
    public double a03 { get; set; }
    public double a04 { get; set; }
    public double a05 { get; set; }
    public double a06 { get; set; }
    public double a07 { get; set; }
    public double a08 { get; set; }
    public double a09 { get; set; }


    public List<ZnormalT> GetZnormalTs()
    {
        var model = new List<ZnormalT>
        {                   //Z_Blpha↓        ///////Z_Alpha →↓ . . .
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0   ,   a0 =    0.5     ,   a01 =   0.504   ,   a02 =   0.508   ,   a03 =   0.512   ,   a04 =   0.516   ,   a05 =   0.5199  ,   a06 =   0.5239  ,   a07 =   0.5279  ,   a08 =   0.5319  ,   a09 =   0.5359  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.1 ,   a0 =    0.5398  ,   a01 =   0.5438  ,   a02 =   0.5478  ,   a03 =   0.5517  ,   a04 =   0.5557  ,   a05 =   0.5596  ,   a06 =   0.5636  ,   a07 =   0.5675  ,   a08 =   0.5714  ,   a09 =   0.5753  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.2 ,   a0 =    0.5793  ,   a01 =   0.5832  ,   a02 =   0.5871  ,   a03 =   0.591   ,   a04 =   0.5948  ,   a05 =   0.5987  ,   a06 =   0.6026  ,   a07 =   0.6064  ,   a08 =   0.6103  ,   a09 =   0.6141  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.3 ,   a0 =    0.6179  ,   a01 =   0.6217  ,   a02 =   0.6255  ,   a03 =   0.6293  ,   a04 =   0.6331  ,   a05 =   0.6368  ,   a06 =   0.6406  ,   a07 =   0.6443  ,   a08 =   0.648   ,   a09 =   0.6517  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.4 ,   a0 =    0.6554  ,   a01 =   0.6591  ,   a02 =   0.6628  ,   a03 =   0.6664  ,   a04 =   0.67    ,   a05 =   0.6736  ,   a06 =   0.6772  ,   a07 =   0.6808  ,   a08 =   0.6844  ,   a09 =   0.6879  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.5 ,   a0 =    0.6915  ,   a01 =   0.695   ,   a02 =   0.6985  ,   a03 =   0.7019  ,   a04 =   0.7054  ,   a05 =   0.7088  ,   a06 =   0.7123  ,   a07 =   0.7157  ,   a08 =   0.719   ,   a09 =   0.7224  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.6 ,   a0 =    0.7257  ,   a01 =   0.7291  ,   a02 =   0.7324  ,   a03 =   0.7357  ,   a04 =   0.7389  ,   a05 =   0.7422  ,   a06 =   0.7454  ,   a07 =   0.7486  ,   a08 =   0.7517  ,   a09 =   0.7549  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.7 ,   a0 =    0.758   ,   a01 =   0.7611  ,   a02 =   0.7642  ,   a03 =   0.7673  ,   a04 =   0.7704  ,   a05 =   0.7734  ,   a06 =   0.7764  ,   a07 =   0.7794  ,   a08 =   0.7823  ,   a09 =   0.7852  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.8 ,   a0 =    0.7881  ,   a01 =   0.791   ,   a02 =   0.7939  ,   a03 =   0.7967  ,   a04 =   0.7995  ,   a05 =   0.8023  ,   a06 =   0.8051  ,   a07 =   0.8078  ,   a08 =   0.8106  ,   a09 =   0.8133  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.9 ,   a0 =    0.8159  ,   a01 =   0.8186  ,   a02 =   0.8212  ,   a03 =   0.8238  ,   a04 =   0.8264  ,   a05 =   0.8289  ,   a06 =   0.8315  ,   a07 =   0.834   ,   a08 =   0.8365  ,   a09 =   0.8389  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1   ,   a0 =    0.8413  ,   a01 =   0.8438  ,   a02 =   0.8461  ,   a03 =   0.8485  ,   a04 =   0.8508  ,   a05 =   0.8531  ,   a06 =   0.8554  ,   a07 =   0.8577  ,   a08 =   0.8599  ,   a09 =   0.8621  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.1 ,   a0 =    0.8643  ,   a01 =   0.8665  ,   a02 =   0.8686  ,   a03 =   0.8708  ,   a04 =   0.8729  ,   a05 =   0.8749  ,   a06 =   0.877   ,   a07 =   0.879   ,   a08 =   0.881   ,   a09 =   0.883   }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.2 ,   a0 =    0.8849  ,   a01 =   0.8869  ,   a02 =   0.8888  ,   a03 =   0.8907  ,   a04 =   0.8925  ,   a05 =   0.8944  ,   a06 =   0.8962  ,   a07 =   0.898   ,   a08 =   0.8997  ,   a09 =   0.9015  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.3 ,   a0 =    0.9032  ,   a01 =   0.9049  ,   a02 =   0.9066  ,   a03 =   0.9082  ,   a04 =   0.9099  ,   a05 =   0.9115  ,   a06 =   0.9131  ,   a07 =   0.9147  ,   a08 =   0.9162  ,   a09 =   0.9177  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.4 ,   a0 =    0.9192  ,   a01 =   0.9207  ,   a02 =   0.9222  ,   a03 =   0.9236  ,   a04 =   0.9251  ,   a05 =   0.9265  ,   a06 =   0.9279  ,   a07 =   0.9292  ,   a08 =   0.9306  ,   a09 =   0.9319  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.5 ,   a0 =    0.9332  ,   a01 =   0.9345  ,   a02 =   0.9357  ,   a03 =   0.937   ,   a04 =   0.9382  ,   a05 =   0.9394  ,   a06 =   0.9406  ,   a07 =   0.9418  ,   a08 =   0.9429  ,   a09 =   0.9441  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.6 ,   a0 =    0.9452  ,   a01 =   0.9463  ,   a02 =   0.9474  ,   a03 =   0.9484  ,   a04 =   0.9495  ,   a05 =   0.9505  ,   a06 =   0.9515  ,   a07 =   0.9525  ,   a08 =   0.9535  ,   a09 =   0.9545  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.7 ,   a0 =    0.9554  ,   a01 =   0.9564  ,   a02 =   0.9573  ,   a03 =   0.9582  ,   a04 =   0.9591  ,   a05 =   0.9599  ,   a06 =   0.9608  ,   a07 =   0.9616  ,   a08 =   0.9625  ,   a09 =   0.9633  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.8 ,   a0 =    0.9641  ,   a01 =   0.9649  ,   a02 =   0.9656  ,   a03 =   0.9664  ,   a04 =   0.9671  ,   a05 =   0.9678  ,   a06 =   0.9686  ,   a07 =   0.9693  ,   a08 =   0.9699  ,   a09 =   0.9706  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.9 ,   a0 =    0.9713  ,   a01 =   0.9719  ,   a02 =   0.9726  ,   a03 =   0.9732  ,   a04 =   0.9738  ,   a05 =   0.9744  ,   a06 =   0.975   ,   a07 =   0.9756  ,   a08 =   0.9761  ,   a09 =   0.9767  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2   ,   a0 =    0.9772  ,   a01 =   0.9778  ,   a02 =   0.9783  ,   a03 =   0.9788  ,   a04 =   0.9793  ,   a05 =   0.9798  ,   a06 =   0.9803  ,   a07 =   0.9808  ,   a08 =   0.9812  ,   a09 =   0.9817  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.1 ,   a0 =    0.9821  ,   a01 =   0.9826  ,   a02 =   0.983   ,   a03 =   0.9834  ,   a04 =   0.9838  ,   a05 =   0.9842  ,   a06 =   0.9846  ,   a07 =   0.985   ,   a08 =   0.9854  ,   a09 =   0.9857  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.2 ,   a0 =    0.9861  ,   a01 =   0.9864  ,   a02 =   0.9868  ,   a03 =   0.9871  ,   a04 =   0.9875  ,   a05 =   0.9878  ,   a06 =   0.9881  ,   a07 =   0.9884  ,   a08 =   0.9887  ,   a09 =   0.989   }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.3 ,   a0 =    0.9893  ,   a01 =   0.9896  ,   a02 =   0.9898  ,   a03 =   0.9901  ,   a04 =   0.9904  ,   a05 =   0.9906  ,   a06 =   0.9909  ,   a07 =   0.9911  ,   a08 =   0.9913  ,   a09 =   0.9916  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.4 ,   a0 =    0.9918  ,   a01 =   0.992   ,   a02 =   0.9922  ,   a03 =   0.9925  ,   a04 =   0.9927  ,   a05 =   0.9929  ,   a06 =   0.9931  ,   a07 =   0.9932  ,   a08 =   0.9934  ,   a09 =   0.9936  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.5 ,   a0 =    0.9938  ,   a01 =   0.994   ,   a02 =   0.9941  ,   a03 =   0.9943  ,   a04 =   0.9945  ,   a05 =   0.9946  ,   a06 =   0.9948  ,   a07 =   0.9949  ,   a08 =   0.9951  ,   a09 =   0.9952  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.6 ,   a0 =    0.9953  ,   a01 =   0.9955  ,   a02 =   0.9956  ,   a03 =   0.9957  ,   a04 =   0.9959  ,   a05 =   0.996   ,   a06 =   0.9961  ,   a07 =   0.9962  ,   a08 =   0.9963  ,   a09 =   0.9964  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.7 ,   a0 =    0.9965  ,   a01 =   0.9966  ,   a02 =   0.9967  ,   a03 =   0.9968  ,   a04 =   0.9969  ,   a05 =   0.997   ,   a06 =   0.9971  ,   a07 =   0.9972  ,   a08 =   0.9973  ,   a09 =   0.9974  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.8 ,   a0 =    0.9974  ,   a01 =   0.9975  ,   a02 =   0.9976  ,   a03 =   0.9977  ,   a04 =   0.9977  ,   a05 =   0.9978  ,   a06 =   0.9979  ,   a07 =   0.9979  ,   a08 =   0.998   ,   a09 =   0.9981  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.9 ,   a0 =    0.9981  ,   a01 =   0.9982  ,   a02 =   0.9982  ,   a03 =   0.9983  ,   a04 =   0.9984  ,   a05 =   0.9984  ,   a06 =   0.9985  ,   a07 =   0.9985  ,   a08 =   0.9986  ,   a09 =   0.9986  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    3   ,   a0 =    0.9987  ,   a01 =   0.9987  ,   a02 =   0.9987  ,   a03 =   0.9988  ,   a04 =   0.9988  ,   a05 =   0.9989  ,   a06 =   0.9989  ,   a07 =   0.9989  ,   a08 =   0.999   ,   a09 =   0.999   }   ,
        };
        return model;
    }
}
```

Code Behind :

```
 private void Btn_Process_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ZnormalT ZTBL = new ZnormalT();
        // as Listy ALL Data in This Table 
        var AllData_Z = ZTBL.GetZnormalTs();
        //Alpha Entered 0.05
        double Alpha_num = Convert.ToDouble(Alpha_Text.Text);
       double closest = AllData_Z.Aggregate<double>((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(y - Alpha_num) ? x : y);
    }


  ERROR :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error   CS1929  'List' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Aggregate(IQueryable, Expression<Func<double, double, double>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18cgg.png)

Please help

Thanks for helping

Comment: You missed a `using System.Linq`?

Comment: No , I  had using System.Linq;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by two things, the second of which I think you did to try and fix the first.

The first problem is this:

```
Math.Abs(x - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(y - Alpha_num)
```

`x` and `y` here are of type `ZnormalT` and `Alpha_num` is of type `double` you need to pick one of the properties to compare with `Alpha_num` like this, I picked the `ZB` property but you can change it to whatever you need.

```
Math.Abs(x.ZB - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(y.ZB - Alpha_num)
```

The second problem is this `AllData_Z.Aggregate<double>` double is the wrong type parameter, now the first problem is fixed, you can just leave it out and the compiler will infer the type.

```
AllData_Z.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x.ZB - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(y.ZB - Alpha_num) ? x : y);
```

I have tidied up some of the variable names and put it into a little test console app below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ZnormalT ZTBL = new ZnormalT();
        // as Listy ALL Data in This Table 
        var AllData_Z = ZTBL.GetZnormalTs();
        //Alpha Entered 0.05
        double Alpha_num = 1.875;
        double result = AllData_Z.Aggregate((closest, next) => Math.Abs(closest.ZB - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(next.ZB - Alpha_num) ? closest : next).ZB;
        Console.WriteLine("Closest is " + result); 
        
    }
}

 public class ZnormalT
{
    public double ZB { get; set; }
    public double a0 { get; set; }
    public double a01 { get; set; }
    public double a02 { get; set; }
    public double a03 { get; set; }
    public double a04 { get; set; }
    public double a05 { get; set; }
    public double a06 { get; set; }
    public double a07 { get; set; }
    public double a08 { get; set; }
    public double a09 { get; set; }


    public List<ZnormalT> GetZnormalTs()
    {
        var model = new List<ZnormalT>
        {                   //Z_Blpha↓        ///////Z_Alpha →↓ . . .
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0   ,   a0 =    0.5     ,   a01 =   0.504   ,   a02 =   0.508   ,   a03 =   0.512   ,   a04 =   0.516   ,   a05 =   0.5199  ,   a06 =   0.5239  ,   a07 =   0.5279  ,   a08 =   0.5319  ,   a09 =   0.5359  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.1 ,   a0 =    0.5398  ,   a01 =   0.5438  ,   a02 =   0.5478  ,   a03 =   0.5517  ,   a04 =   0.5557  ,   a05 =   0.5596  ,   a06 =   0.5636  ,   a07 =   0.5675  ,   a08 =   0.5714  ,   a09 =   0.5753  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.2 ,   a0 =    0.5793  ,   a01 =   0.5832  ,   a02 =   0.5871  ,   a03 =   0.591   ,   a04 =   0.5948  ,   a05 =   0.5987  ,   a06 =   0.6026  ,   a07 =   0.6064  ,   a08 =   0.6103  ,   a09 =   0.6141  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.3 ,   a0 =    0.6179  ,   a01 =   0.6217  ,   a02 =   0.6255  ,   a03 =   0.6293  ,   a04 =   0.6331  ,   a05 =   0.6368  ,   a06 =   0.6406  ,   a07 =   0.6443  ,   a08 =   0.648   ,   a09 =   0.6517  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.4 ,   a0 =    0.6554  ,   a01 =   0.6591  ,   a02 =   0.6628  ,   a03 =   0.6664  ,   a04 =   0.67    ,   a05 =   0.6736  ,   a06 =   0.6772  ,   a07 =   0.6808  ,   a08 =   0.6844  ,   a09 =   0.6879  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.5 ,   a0 =    0.6915  ,   a01 =   0.695   ,   a02 =   0.6985  ,   a03 =   0.7019  ,   a04 =   0.7054  ,   a05 =   0.7088  ,   a06 =   0.7123  ,   a07 =   0.7157  ,   a08 =   0.719   ,   a09 =   0.7224  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.6 ,   a0 =    0.7257  ,   a01 =   0.7291  ,   a02 =   0.7324  ,   a03 =   0.7357  ,   a04 =   0.7389  ,   a05 =   0.7422  ,   a06 =   0.7454  ,   a07 =   0.7486  ,   a08 =   0.7517  ,   a09 =   0.7549  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.7 ,   a0 =    0.758   ,   a01 =   0.7611  ,   a02 =   0.7642  ,   a03 =   0.7673  ,   a04 =   0.7704  ,   a05 =   0.7734  ,   a06 =   0.7764  ,   a07 =   0.7794  ,   a08 =   0.7823  ,   a09 =   0.7852  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.8 ,   a0 =    0.7881  ,   a01 =   0.791   ,   a02 =   0.7939  ,   a03 =   0.7967  ,   a04 =   0.7995  ,   a05 =   0.8023  ,   a06 =   0.8051  ,   a07 =   0.8078  ,   a08 =   0.8106  ,   a09 =   0.8133  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    0.9 ,   a0 =    0.8159  ,   a01 =   0.8186  ,   a02 =   0.8212  ,   a03 =   0.8238  ,   a04 =   0.8264  ,   a05 =   0.8289  ,   a06 =   0.8315  ,   a07 =   0.834   ,   a08 =   0.8365  ,   a09 =   0.8389  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1   ,   a0 =    0.8413  ,   a01 =   0.8438  ,   a02 =   0.8461  ,   a03 =   0.8485  ,   a04 =   0.8508  ,   a05 =   0.8531  ,   a06 =   0.8554  ,   a07 =   0.8577  ,   a08 =   0.8599  ,   a09 =   0.8621  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.1 ,   a0 =    0.8643  ,   a01 =   0.8665  ,   a02 =   0.8686  ,   a03 =   0.8708  ,   a04 =   0.8729  ,   a05 =   0.8749  ,   a06 =   0.877   ,   a07 =   0.879   ,   a08 =   0.881   ,   a09 =   0.883   }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.2 ,   a0 =    0.8849  ,   a01 =   0.8869  ,   a02 =   0.8888  ,   a03 =   0.8907  ,   a04 =   0.8925  ,   a05 =   0.8944  ,   a06 =   0.8962  ,   a07 =   0.898   ,   a08 =   0.8997  ,   a09 =   0.9015  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.3 ,   a0 =    0.9032  ,   a01 =   0.9049  ,   a02 =   0.9066  ,   a03 =   0.9082  ,   a04 =   0.9099  ,   a05 =   0.9115  ,   a06 =   0.9131  ,   a07 =   0.9147  ,   a08 =   0.9162  ,   a09 =   0.9177  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.4 ,   a0 =    0.9192  ,   a01 =   0.9207  ,   a02 =   0.9222  ,   a03 =   0.9236  ,   a04 =   0.9251  ,   a05 =   0.9265  ,   a06 =   0.9279  ,   a07 =   0.9292  ,   a08 =   0.9306  ,   a09 =   0.9319  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.5 ,   a0 =    0.9332  ,   a01 =   0.9345  ,   a02 =   0.9357  ,   a03 =   0.937   ,   a04 =   0.9382  ,   a05 =   0.9394  ,   a06 =   0.9406  ,   a07 =   0.9418  ,   a08 =   0.9429  ,   a09 =   0.9441  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.6 ,   a0 =    0.9452  ,   a01 =   0.9463  ,   a02 =   0.9474  ,   a03 =   0.9484  ,   a04 =   0.9495  ,   a05 =   0.9505  ,   a06 =   0.9515  ,   a07 =   0.9525  ,   a08 =   0.9535  ,   a09 =   0.9545  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.7 ,   a0 =    0.9554  ,   a01 =   0.9564  ,   a02 =   0.9573  ,   a03 =   0.9582  ,   a04 =   0.9591  ,   a05 =   0.9599  ,   a06 =   0.9608  ,   a07 =   0.9616  ,   a08 =   0.9625  ,   a09 =   0.9633  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.8 ,   a0 =    0.9641  ,   a01 =   0.9649  ,   a02 =   0.9656  ,   a03 =   0.9664  ,   a04 =   0.9671  ,   a05 =   0.9678  ,   a06 =   0.9686  ,   a07 =   0.9693  ,   a08 =   0.9699  ,   a09 =   0.9706  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    1.9 ,   a0 =    0.9713  ,   a01 =   0.9719  ,   a02 =   0.9726  ,   a03 =   0.9732  ,   a04 =   0.9738  ,   a05 =   0.9744  ,   a06 =   0.975   ,   a07 =   0.9756  ,   a08 =   0.9761  ,   a09 =   0.9767  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2   ,   a0 =    0.9772  ,   a01 =   0.9778  ,   a02 =   0.9783  ,   a03 =   0.9788  ,   a04 =   0.9793  ,   a05 =   0.9798  ,   a06 =   0.9803  ,   a07 =   0.9808  ,   a08 =   0.9812  ,   a09 =   0.9817  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.1 ,   a0 =    0.9821  ,   a01 =   0.9826  ,   a02 =   0.983   ,   a03 =   0.9834  ,   a04 =   0.9838  ,   a05 =   0.9842  ,   a06 =   0.9846  ,   a07 =   0.985   ,   a08 =   0.9854  ,   a09 =   0.9857  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.2 ,   a0 =    0.9861  ,   a01 =   0.9864  ,   a02 =   0.9868  ,   a03 =   0.9871  ,   a04 =   0.9875  ,   a05 =   0.9878  ,   a06 =   0.9881  ,   a07 =   0.9884  ,   a08 =   0.9887  ,   a09 =   0.989   }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.3 ,   a0 =    0.9893  ,   a01 =   0.9896  ,   a02 =   0.9898  ,   a03 =   0.9901  ,   a04 =   0.9904  ,   a05 =   0.9906  ,   a06 =   0.9909  ,   a07 =   0.9911  ,   a08 =   0.9913  ,   a09 =   0.9916  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.4 ,   a0 =    0.9918  ,   a01 =   0.992   ,   a02 =   0.9922  ,   a03 =   0.9925  ,   a04 =   0.9927  ,   a05 =   0.9929  ,   a06 =   0.9931  ,   a07 =   0.9932  ,   a08 =   0.9934  ,   a09 =   0.9936  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.5 ,   a0 =    0.9938  ,   a01 =   0.994   ,   a02 =   0.9941  ,   a03 =   0.9943  ,   a04 =   0.9945  ,   a05 =   0.9946  ,   a06 =   0.9948  ,   a07 =   0.9949  ,   a08 =   0.9951  ,   a09 =   0.9952  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.6 ,   a0 =    0.9953  ,   a01 =   0.9955  ,   a02 =   0.9956  ,   a03 =   0.9957  ,   a04 =   0.9959  ,   a05 =   0.996   ,   a06 =   0.9961  ,   a07 =   0.9962  ,   a08 =   0.9963  ,   a09 =   0.9964  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.7 ,   a0 =    0.9965  ,   a01 =   0.9966  ,   a02 =   0.9967  ,   a03 =   0.9968  ,   a04 =   0.9969  ,   a05 =   0.997   ,   a06 =   0.9971  ,   a07 =   0.9972  ,   a08 =   0.9973  ,   a09 =   0.9974  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.8 ,   a0 =    0.9974  ,   a01 =   0.9975  ,   a02 =   0.9976  ,   a03 =   0.9977  ,   a04 =   0.9977  ,   a05 =   0.9978  ,   a06 =   0.9979  ,   a07 =   0.9979  ,   a08 =   0.998   ,   a09 =   0.9981  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    2.9 ,   a0 =    0.9981  ,   a01 =   0.9982  ,   a02 =   0.9982  ,   a03 =   0.9983  ,   a04 =   0.9984  ,   a05 =   0.9984  ,   a06 =   0.9985  ,   a07 =   0.9985  ,   a08 =   0.9986  ,   a09 =   0.9986  }   ,
             new ZnormalT   {   ZB =    3   ,   a0 =    0.9987  ,   a01 =   0.9987  ,   a02 =   0.9987  ,   a03 =   0.9988  ,   a04 =   0.9988  ,   a05 =   0.9989  ,   a06 =   0.9989  ,   a07 =   0.9989  ,   a08 =   0.999   ,   a09 =   0.999   }   ,
        };
        return model;
    }
}
```

As per your comment, if you want to find the closest number across all the properties then you just need to change the query to the one below.

```
double result = AllData_Z.SelectMany(x => new [] {x.a0, x.a01, x.a02, x.a03, x.a04, x.a05, x.a06, x.a07, x.a08, x.a09, x.ZB })
.Aggregate((closest, next) => Math.Abs(closest - Alpha_num) < Math.Abs(next - Alpha_num) ? closest : next);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ,is there any way to search in whole ZnormalT for Closest Number ?